# Error with HTTPS for routes in Laravel 4.2 - assets load fine over HTTPS

Tags: php, .htaccess, ssl, https, laravel-4.2

Laravel 4.2

I have been trying to load the app over HTTPS, it just gives 500 Internal Server Error.

SSL has been installed and works fine if any of the file is accessed directly using https e.g. https://domain.com/info.php (info.php is in xyz folder - xyz folder is explained below)

My app is in subfolder (e.g. xyz) of httpdocs. Below is the .htaccess under root (httpdocs) folder;

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^leaf
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ xyz/$1 [L]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    #RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Below is .htaccess under xyz folder;

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

UPDATE:
Found the issue (but not the solution yet), looks like nothing to do with Laravel. Somehow requests over https uses old version of PHP. Just trying to figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vhost_ssl.conf configuration file had to be corrected to use correct version of PHP.